# Using mutex C# for Inno setup

Tags: c#, mutex

Avast detect all software which uses C# Mutex like a virus.

I need to use but i am not able to, code:

```
private static Mutex meuPrograma;

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     bool createdNew;
     using (var setupMutex = new Mutex(false, @"Alpino"))
     {
          Application.Run(new Form1());
     }
}
```

Avast detects it like virus.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I removed the Inno Setup tag since it is purely related to C#.

Comment: Have you attempted to do it the way MSDN suggests? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx What exactly is avast saying? Have you researched avast docs at all?

Comment: What anti virus software causes this false alarm? And what does your application do? Is that code the only code that is in your application?

Comment: @RononDex, Avast Anti-virus

Comment: Try to comment out all usages of the class `Mutex` in your code. Is Avast still complaining?